# How to relinquish MacOS Camera,Microphone

Tags: swift, macos

In trying to code up a prototype, it struct me there's no way revert the request?

So, you add the entitlements of interest to your app's capabilities, and here is I check:

```
internal func avStatus(for media: AVMediaType) -> AVAuthorizationStatus {
    let status = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: media)
    switch status {
        case .authorized: // The user has previously granted access to the microphone.
            return .authorized
        
        case .notDetermined: // The user has not yet been asked for microphone access.
            return .notDetermined
        
        case .denied: // The user has previously denied access.
            return .denied

        case .restricted: // The user can't grant access due to restrictions.
            return .restricted
        default:
            Swift.print("Unknown AV status \(status) for .audio")
            return status
    }
}
```

I was thinking that a user action to request the use of the entitlement, and relinquish would be needed:

```
@objc @IBAction func audioVideoServicesPress(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let service = sender.title.components(separatedBy: " ").last
    let media : AVMediaType = service == "Audio" ? .audio : .video
    let status = self.avStatus(for: media)
    
    guard ![.denied,.restricted].contains(status) else { return }
    
    if status == .authorized {
        print("how do we relinquish need in the a/v device")
    }
    else
    {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: media, completionHandler: { granted in
               return
        })
    }
}
```

In other user actions, if they had disabled or denied, then I would route them to the proper settings app, but before I get there, how to undo the request?

This is no way to un-request access the a/v device?

I think that suggests I'm going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to "relinquish."

The user's button press is an *intent*. The user wants to perform some action that can be performed only if you have authorization. So if you have it or can get, your job now is to *do* it.

Okay, so either you have authorization or you don't. If authorization status is `.undetermined`, you *might* get it. If it's `.authorized`, you already *did* get it. In either of those cases, do what the user intends!

- At the time of your `print` line, you *have* authorization so now go ahead and *do* whatever the user pressed the button intending to do.
- Similarly, do not `return` in the completion handler for requesting access; instead, check `granted` and if true, *do* whatever the user pressed the button intending to do.

In any other case, you are hosed, so do nothing. The user's intent requires an authorization you don't have and cannot get. You might put up a dialog explaining why you can't do it, or send them off to where they can access their settings, but that's all you can do from here.

Comment: I guess I was wanting a similarity to location services.

Comment: What similarity exactly did you have in mind? Do you mean start/stop updates? That has nothing to do with authorization. You cannot unauthorize yourself from location services either.

Comment: The presentation to the user is all I'm after, that when they say 'No' I'll do within reason to  satisfy, as for location I would stop monitoring/updating **and** release my manager object. Anything held should be easily releasable, not clumsy that it requires an app restart and/or privacy app session to deny the app access, when all I wanted to to just show and verify a stop interest or hold on a resource or device.

Comment: Well, if they say "No", you will know because your guard clause will execute: `guard ![.denied,.restricted].contains(status) else { return }`. So instead of just `return`, if you have resources you wish to release, release them (though I cannot imagine what they might be). I really do not at all understand what you want to know that my answer does not tell you.

Comment: I am not understanding anything I think; just feel a request function would be mated to a relinquish; if you disagree that's quite alright, but I'm not a fan is all.

Comment: You might be used to some world where there is a "relinquish", but no iOS / macOS authorization request has one. I would try to be more helpful but I am unable to imagine what a "relinquish" would mean.

Comment: OK, in the interest of others; if I request something, I should within the same context be able to release or relinquish it.  However, for entitlements, it appears you have to venture to the privacy app to affect (release/relinquish). However, this effect is **quite**  different than if I had never make the request.  That's what I was after. How does one restore the environment - aka relinquish a request to where it was before? My only solution thus far is to send them to the privacy app url but as I said their state re: the entitlement is now **quite** different than at start.  Not a fan.